# How to make a select statement in update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a table, and the Where clause should contain the last (or max) from a certain column, so I made this query:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Ordermethod='Pickup'
WHERE orderid IN (
  SELECT MAX(orderid)
  FROM Orders);
```

But, for some reason I don't understand, mysql returns this error:

> 1093 - You can't specify target table 'Bestellingen' for update in FROM clause

I tried different queries, which aren't working either...
Can someone help??

*Sorry for the crappy english*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a MySQL limitation. (As [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) puts it: "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.") You can work around the limitation by writing your subquery as `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) t)`, so that MySQL will create a temporary table for you:

```
UPDATE Orders
   SET Ordermethod='Pickup'
 WHERE orderid IN
        ( SELECT *
            FROM ( SELECT MAX(orderid)
                     FROM Orders
                 ) t
        )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE Orders
>   SET Ordermethod='Pickup'
>   WHERE orderid IN( SELECT MAX(orderid) FROM
>                (
>                   SELECT * FROM Orders
>                ) 
>                    AS c1 
>                    )